# Strange error using .values on a Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have this dictionary

```
var codiceValutaDict: [String : Character] = ["us": "$", "it": "€", "fr": "€"]
```

Trying to do an array with only keys or value using

```
var keysArray: [String] = codiceValutaDict.keys
```

I get this error:

> 'LazyForwardCollection, String>>' is not convertible to '[String]'

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let codiceValutaDict: [String : Character] = ["us": "$", "it":"€", "fr":"€"]

let keysArray = codiceValutaDict.keys.array // ["us", "it", "fr"]
```

Comment: This looks like the most compact way to do it.

Comment: Simple and effective!

Answer (score 3):

**Create an Array out of a LazyForwardCollection**

Just pass the collection to the proper Initializer of the Array-Class

```
var keys:[String] = Array(codiceValutaDict.keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the type of keys [here](http://swiftdoc.org/type/Dictionary/):

```
var keys: LazyForwardCollection<MapCollectionView<[Key : Value], Key>> { get }
```

It is not an array of strings.
You have to use the array constructor to create an array of strings from that:

```
var keysArray: [String] = [String](codiceValutaDict.keys)
```